# I am fairly new to Java. I am attempting to read excel file and getting error from slf4j

Tags: java, log4j, apache-poi, slf4j

I am attempting to read excel file and getting error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory:
method 'void <init>()' not found
```

Code inspired by: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

Code:

```
package nov2021;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
// import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
public class readWriteExcel {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
  File file = new File("C:\\Users\\brlaw\\Documents\\Learn IT\\Simplilearn\\Core Java\\HelloWorld\\Input data\\Family.xlsx");

  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
  Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
  System.out.println(cell);
  wb.close();
 }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory: method 'void <init>()' not found
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:53)     
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:41)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext.getLogger(SLF4JLoggerContext.java:36)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContext.getLogger(LoggerContext.java:99)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:43)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FileMagic.valueOf(FileMagic.java:209)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:222)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:185)
at nov2021.readWriteExcel.main(readWriteExcel.java:20)
```

NOTES: I have downloaded and added the following prior to execution:

1. Apache poi 5.2.1 JAR files in the class path
2. Apache-log4j-2.17.2 JAR files
3. Logger factory 2.2.0 JAR

#### Update March 18 2022:

As per comments from Axel R, I removed all JARs related to SLF4J and also logger factory and here is what I get as error.

##### ERROR

ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
null

#### [ FIXED! ]Update March 19 2022

1. Based on the comment from Axel R in stack overflow there was a log4j distribution link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.17.2
   Installed log4j-core-2.17.2 replacing the log4j-core-2.17.1 that was part of the POI distribution.
2. log4j-api-2.17.2 was listed as a dependency in the same hyperlink that Axel R provided. This Fixed the issue.

Comment: Please do your best to make your question self-contained, includes code and errors, without links to sketchy off-site resources like personal storage.

Comment: The error is not about `apache poi` but seems to be resulting from a mismatch in `log4j` and `slf4j`. I would ask the logging experts by tagging this question appropriate.

Comment: Axel, I see you have already placed the tags log4j & slf4j. What needs to be done for the appropriate log4j support community to be able to see this question, I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: I doubt you can do anything more. I can't answer this as I'm trying to avoid these logging frameworks for security reasons. So all you can do is wait and see if the question draws attention.

Comment: is this the 'Logger factory 2.2.0' - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.lsn/logger-factory/2.2.0 ? This is not built for log4j 2.17.x.

Comment: have you read https://poi.apache.org/components/logging.html - describes how logging works with better known approaches like log4j-core and logback

Comment: I don't have any intention to use log4j. I added log4j after i saw this error first: "ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
null". All I need is to be able to read an excel file (XLSX) It looks like apache poi is using log4j internally and somehow there is error faced. If anyone can provide a working sample code to be able to loop thru excel (latest version) to read and store into a 2 dimensional array, that will do

Comment: Do simple remove all `slf4j` jars from class path then? Especially your "Logger factory 2.2.0 JAR".

Comment: Axel, I removed the slf4j jars and logger factory and I am getting error as updated in the body text above

Comment: I told you to remove `slf4j` but not to remove `log4j`. `Apache poi` needs `log4j`. As told by the error you need https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.17.2.

Comment: Yes, I only removed slf4j and loggerfactory. The log4j-core-2.17.1 was still there, as it is part of the POI distribution. Your link showed log4j-core-2.17.2 , so I now removed 2.17.1 and added this 2.17.2 version/build. Now I am getting different error. Do I need to install the dependencies that are listed as well. Most of them shows optional.

Comment: It WORKED !! . In the same link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.17.2 that you provided in the comment above , there were dependencies listed, most of them were optional, but log4j-api-2.17.2 was not. I installed it and it worked! . Thank you so much for the help